# Server as Service in background for Android?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, android-service

I have a notification hanler which manages to notify the user by means of various ways (Snachbar, NotificationManager).

I would like to enhance this functionality by adding a service to that notification manager, which runs always in the background and waits/listens for notifications from the back-end.

When I trigger a message from my back-end like "Please update your app from PlayStore" it should be shown to the user. (I know how to do this, when I trigger that from the mobile by a REST call to my endpoint.) But I don't know, if it is possible to listen (on a port or something) as a server?

Comment: Read about push notifications - https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ . There is no need to reinvent a bicycle - android provides everything you need for that task.

Comment: you don't know about push notifications  ?

Comment: @Divers I tried that example at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start That is working very well. I am trying to create that google-service.json and let it work with all my other apps, since I plan to release this as a library.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you already have a server able to send notifications/messages, the best way to receive notifications/messages on an Android phone is to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging.

You will have to create a Firebase project [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/)

It is Google's official way to implement what you want to do.
The [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is really well done and easy to understand.

Comment: No FIrebase. Friend is preparing another backend (AWS)

Comment: FCM Android SDK is to be used on the front end, Android devices. Even if your friend is preparing a backend, you still need to add FCM to your app to catch the messages

Comment: Again no firebase, since we are not allowed to store our users/clients to/in their backend

Comment: I think you don't get it. Firebase offers a lot of services, but you dont need them all. I'm talking about the FCM SDK, which is just a client for push notification. To send push notification to an Android device, your server will have to send it to Firebase (checkout the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server). Once Firebase got it, it will propagate it to your app. But it needs to implement the FCM SDK

Answer (score 0):

You must have a end-point that it will return boolean value. The app is first run when you check the end-point. İf it's true then you'll show a dialog "Please update your app from PlayStore"